# XML with XSLT multiple tags

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I would like to interpret a file.xml to file.txt, this is not a problem but when I try to "take" many things in different tags.

Please take a look at my file.xml :

```
<racine>
        <balise1>
                 <info>
                      <Commercial>1000</Commercial>
                      <OrdId>42</OrdId>
                      <CustomerId>314159</CustomerId>
                 </info>
        </balise1>
        <balise2>
                 <info2>
                       <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                       <Price>10.0</Price>
                       <Currency>CHF</Currency>
                 </info2>
        </balise2>
</racine>
```

I want this output;

```
Commercial,Order,CustomerId,Quantity,Price,Currency
1000,42,314159,1,10.0,CHF
```

I tried many solutions, but I'm a noob in XSLT.

Here is an example of my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSl/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>Commercial,OrdId,CustomerId,Quantity,Price,Currency</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="racine"/>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="racine">
<xsl:apply-templates select="balise1/info"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info">
  <xsl:value-of select="Commercial"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="OrdId"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="CustomerId"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="balise2/info2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info2">
<xsl:value-of select="ItemQuantity"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="PriceValue"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="CurrencyCode"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you please add the desired output and - if you already try something - your current xslt.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/balise

Answer (score 2):

You have two templates matching `"info"` which is considered an error in XSLT. From looking at what you require, the body of the second template should probably be called from the template matching `racine`

```
<xsl:template match="racine">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="balise1/info"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="balise2/info2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Other things to note

1. Namespaces are case-sensitive. You had specified the xsl namespace as `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSl/Transform` when it should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`
2. Your `info2` template was referring to elements which did not exist in the XML.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>Commercial,OrdId,CustomerId,Quantity,Price,Currency</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="racine"/>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="racine">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="balise1/info"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="balise2/info2"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info">
  <xsl:value-of select="Commercial"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="OrdId"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="CustomerId"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info2">
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Currency"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your input has fixed format than you can handle this easily in **XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Commercial,OrdId,CustomerId,Quantity,Price,Currency</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="racine">
    <xsl:value-of select="balise1/info/*|balise2/info2/*" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: can't use XSLT2.0 must be 1.0

Answer (score -1):

```
Check this code

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>Commercial,OrdId,CustomerId,Quantity,Price,Currency</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="racine"/>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info">
<xsl:value-of select="Commercial"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="OrdId"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="CustomerId"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info2">
<xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Currency"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```